# Is there a known composition function for the type signature (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> (b, c))?

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I've been working for a while in an algorithm that requires composing it's function parts so that the return value of the composition contains the output of both functions. For example (in JavaScript):

```
const double = x => x * 2
const increment = x => x + 1

const doubleThenIncrement = composeConservingOutputs(increment, double)

doubleThenIncrement(2) -- => [4, 5]
```

I've been wondering if this is a known composition pattern. In [Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html), this seems to be achievable in a clean way piping the output of one arrow to the fanout of the other arrow and id:

```
import Control.Arrow 

double = (*) 2
increment = (+) 1

doubleThenIncrement = arr double >>> (arr id &&& arr increment)
```

but I couldn't find if this composition is a common/known pattern or not.

I find this useful because it allows to very easily inspect the output of the intermediate functions for debugging, which made me think this is probably a thing already.

A [Hoogle search for the pattern (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> (b, c))](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%20-%3E%20b%29%20-%3E%20%28b%20-%3E%20c%29%20-%3E%20%28a%20-%3E%20%28b%2C%20c%29%29) proves unfruitful.

Thanks

Comment: Your function is `\f g -> (id &&& g) . f` -- functions have an `Arrow` instance, so if you are only dealing with plain functions you don't need `arr`.

Comment: Or `\f g -> ((,) <*> g) . f`. Which can be spelled as `flip $ (.) . ap (,)`.

Answer (score 4):

With no additional imports, you can use

```
doubleThenIncrement = fmap increment . (id >>= (,)) . double
```

This function first doubles its argument, then uses the `Monad` instance of functions to use return value of `double` as *both* arguments for the `(,)` function, then applies `increment` to the *second* of the elements in the resulting tuple.

With one import, you can simplify the middle part a little:

```
import Control.Monad
doubleThenIncrement = fmap increment . join (,) . double
```

(For functions, the implementation of `join` is effectively `join f = \x -> f x x`. We call `(,)` using the result of `double` for both arguments. `join (,) . double` is `\x -> (,) (double x) (double x)` is `(double x, double x)`.)

You can define a function that takes `increment` and `double` as arguments to return `doubleThenIncrement`:

```
> let composePreservingOutputs f g = fmap f . join (,) . g
> composePreservingOutputs increment double $ 2
(4,5)
```

---

In all its horrific point-free glory, it would be

```
-- Courtesy of pointfree.io
composePreservingOutputs = (. (join (,) .)) . (.) . fmap
```

---

(Or, you could just write

```
composePreservingOutputs f g x = (f x, g (f x))
```

but where's the fun in that?)

Comment: Some more regolfing: (1) `composePreservingOutputs` can also be written as `\f g -> fmap f . ((,) <*> id) . g`, taking advantage of the fact that the  `Monad` and `Applicative` instances for functions do essentially the same thing. (2) Having the `Applicative` expression swallow the `fmap` on the tuple leads to `((,) <*> f) . g` (that also can be done with the `(>>=)` version, but an extra `flip` is necessary). (3) Adding a redundant `(<$> id)` leads to `((,) <$> id <*> f) . g` (a.k.a. `liftA2 (,) id f . g`), which makes the fact that this is another way to spell `(id &&& f) . g` more evident.

Comment: Nice. I started playing around with an applicative approach, but gave up to avoid burning my entire day on this one problem :)

Answer (score 2):

It's tricky to come up with general solution for what you want in Haskell because the intermediate values need to be of the same type.

The pattern of logging out intermediate values is something that the `Writer` monad is suited to. The restriction here is that the "written" values must implement the `Monoid` typeclass. I suspect this is OK in your case if you are just using this for debugging, i.e. you can convert the values to `String`, which is a `Monoid`.

I would define a function `writeParam f x = (show x, f x)` if you like arrows) which you can wrap all your functions in. Functions which return tuples `Monoid a => ((,) a)` are actually a simple implementation of the writer monad, so you can then compose these functions with regular monad composition like so:

```
doubleThenIncrement :: (Num n, Show n) => n -> (String, n)
doubleThenIncrement = writeParam double >=> writeParam increment
```

By the way, if you like arrows, you could also define `writeParam` as `writeParam = (show &&&)` or even just `writeParam = (id &&&)` if you want to be more generic. Although IMO this is less clear.